# What is Ethernet adapter Bluetooth Network Connection:?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, ethernet, bluetooth

```
Ethernet adapter Bluetooth Network Connection:
    Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
    Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
    Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Bluetooth Device (Personal Area Network)
    Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 50-xx-xx-xx-xx-F7
    DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
    Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
```

May i know what does Ethernet adapter Bluetooth Network Connection: means? As far as I know, ethernet is referring to wired connection but bluetooth is a wireless connection. And even my laptop is paired with my phone and the bluetooth is working fine, it shows media disconnected.

Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

The interface shows up as Ethernet because Bluetooth PAN actually imitates Ethernet from the higher layers' point of view – the Bluetooth messages encapsulate whole Ethernet frames (with MAC addresses and such).

This means that instead of having to learn a completely new interface type, network tools (and IP itself) can just handle it like a traditional wired Ethernet interface.

*(Wi-Fi does the same, actually. Although real Wi-Fi frames have a different structure, programs just see completely Ethernet-like frames when they use a Wi-Fi interface.)*

Answer (score 0):

That's a virtual Bluetooth *network* adapter mimicking Ethernet. If you don't use the Bluetooth *networking* profile it's disconnected.

Comment: So does it mean that if I'm not using bluetooth to transmit data or whatsoever, it will just show disconnected? even if it is paired with another device

Comment: Bluetooth uses any of a number of connection profiles. Networking is just one of them ( and rarely used).